# how to create this interesting vector

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop

I was wondering if anyone could help me figure out how this asset was created (credit: Travis Brothers, Post Malone tour advertisement). It looks like a firework, but I have tried vectoring early firework explosions and cannot seem to get the same effect. It might also be a sort of time travel lens flare.

Or, it has been made from scratch with some threshold adjustments, etc. And if this is the case, I am curious how it would have been achieved. Custom shape? Textured brushes?

Thanks for any and all the help.

[image]

Comment: Could simply be a brush in Illustrator and **drawn**. There's nothing which excludes the possibility that, using a drawing tablet, a simple scribble is made. Assuming everything is some "filtered" or "traced" photo is not always the correct mindset.

Comment: @Scott, you are right in why that is a misleading assumption. But, given the detail of the crimping, and the rounded edges I am inclined to think it IS a first a traced (or filtered) image that has then been tweaked. But I am unsure.. Thanks for your advice!

Comment: To be honest it looks like an auto trace of a badly printed image, maybe something that has been photocopied a couple of times.

Comment: I was thinking scan of a squiggle on cardboard or a "laid" stock.. then traced maybe.

Comment: It looks like a bad trace of a paint splat as opposed to a firework.

Answer (score 1):

Look for a paint or ink splat to trace instead of fireworks.  The uneven and inconsistent lines would be more appropriate.

Like this one:
[Getty Images Paint Splat](https://www.gettyimages.com/detail/photo/small-paint-splat-royalty-free-image/157187251)

Comment: thank you very much, that tip was super helpful :).

Comment: Very welcome! No to just find the right splat.